# Yii2 executing a sql server stored procedure from button

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have a sql server stored procedure sp_annualupdate that I want to call and run from a button using Yii2.
Any advise on coding controller and view much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's straight forward, in your controller public function add the following code:

```
$connection = Yii::$app->db;
$command = $connection->createCommand('sp_annualupdate');     
$command->execute();
```